# Getting unique rows in a numpy array preserving original order

Tags: python, unique, numpy-ndarray, palette

I'm trying to read the colors of this palette into a numpy array:

[image]

First I get all the colours along a 1-pixel wide column:

```
  im_in = Image.open(inputfile)
  im_in = im_in.convert('RGBA').crop((50, 88, 50 + 1, 88 + 1049))
```

Then I convert the image into a numpy array and use the [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function to get unique columns.

```
  scale = np.array(im_in).squeeze()
  a, indx = np.unique(scale, axis=0, return_index=True)
  colors = scale[indx]
```

Now, the problem is that the order of the colours is not preserved:

```
  cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('asdf', np.array(colors) / 255, 
                                     N=len(colors))
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
  fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
  norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=5, vmax=10)
  fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm),
               cax=ax, orientation='horizontal', label='Some Units')
  fig.show()
```

And I get this shuffled array:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with the `unique` function?

Comment: Have you try sorting your data ? Either `a` or `scale `

Comment: I sort `scale` according to the returned index when I define colours in third line of third block of code.